# Is there a way to capture specific REQUESTS made on the front-end of a Shopify website from my Shopify App?

Tags: shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I have Shopify CLI app, made using Node.JS, and I want it to detect when a customer submits "/cart/add" or "/cart/change" on the front-end. I need it to be consistent, so I figured if I can intercept those page request on a server-side level, it would work regardless of the theme.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Shopify Cart Webhook](https://shopify.dev/api/admin/rest/reference/events/webhook) which send to complete details about cart when it item create and update